# Edit Jazzy HTML generation to add custom link

Tags: jazzy

I would like to add a link to our main documentation page to every jazzy-generated page. Can anyone point me to the code where the html is actually built? I looked at all the customization options and none of them do what I want. I’ve also looked through the code for a while but so far have not found what I would need to edit.

Comment: I looked at the customization options again and it looks like I just need to create a custom theme and pass the path to the `theme` option:  `--theme docs/themes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: 
https://github.com/realm/jazzy/blob/master/lib/jazzy/themes/[theme]/templates/doc.mustache

For example, for the apple theme:
https://github.com/realm/jazzy/blob/master/lib/jazzy/themes/apple/templates/doc.mustache